# How to use webchimera.js/node.js for rtsp streaming

Tags: node.js, eclipse, jsp, web-applications

In my web application i am using VLC player to play RTSP streaming, but now chrome has completely stopped NPAPI. After this my customer couldn't stream their camera in the browser.
My manager suggested me to use webchimera.js and node.js to test streaming in browser, but i am new to this could any one please suggest how can i use these technology in my java project

Answer (score 1):

`WebChimera.js` could not be used with regular browser. It could be used only with [NW.js](http://nwjs.io/) or [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) or any other `Node.js` based frameworks.

Comment: Then, How can can achieve RTSP streaming on browser without NPAPI??